# gulp-zip // zip files without zipping them into a folder?

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

Anyone who knows how to gulp-zip files without zipping the files into a folder?

```
//NOT THIS 

folder.zip
|-folder
  |-file1
  |-file2
  |-file3


//BUT THIS

folder.zip
|-file1
|-file2
|-file3
```